# Show that $x_{n}-\sqrt{2\ln(n)}$ converges to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

We have the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_{n}+\frac{1}{nx_{n}}$ with $x_{1}>0$. Show that the limit of the sequence $(x_{n}-\sqrt{2\ln(n)})=0$.
I showed that $x_{n}$ has limit $\infty$. Then I showed that the limit of the sequence $\frac{x_{n}}{\sqrt{2\ln(n)}}$ is 1. I tried calculating the limit that we want to show is 0, but I think I got something wrong and I dont know why.
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(x_{n}-\sqrt{2\ln(n)}\right)
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{2}\frac{\frac{x_{n}}{\sqrt{2\ln(n)}}-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(n)}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{2}\frac{\frac{x_{n+1}}{\sqrt{2\ln(n+1)}}-\frac{x_{n}}{\sqrt{2\ln(n)}}}{\frac{\sqrt{\ln(n)}-\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}}{\sqrt{\ln(n)\ln(n+1)}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\ln(n)}x_{n+1}-\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}x_{n}}{\sqrt{\ln(n)}-\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}}
\end{align} that is infinity. What I did wrong and how I can do this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got that last limit to be infinity, but here's an outline of one way to solve this problem.

First, notice that $$x_{n+1}^2 = \left(x_n + \dfrac{1}{nx_n}\right)^2 = x_n^2 + \dfrac{2}{n} + \dfrac{1}{n^2x_n^2}.$$

It is easy to check that $\{x_n\}$ is increasing. So you can bound $$x_n^2 + \dfrac{2}{n} \le x_{n+1}^2 \le x_n^2 + \dfrac{2}{n} + \dfrac{1}{n^2x_1^2}$$ $$\dfrac{2}{n} \le x_{n+1}^2 - x_n^2 \le  \dfrac{2}{n} + \dfrac{1}{n^2x_1^2}$$

Now, sum this from $n = 1$ to $N - 1$ and see if you can get that $x_N^2 - 2\ln N$ is bounded by constants as $N \to \infty$. From there, it will be easy to show that $\lim_{N \to \infty}(x_N - \sqrt{2\ln N}) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I said that the last limit is infinity beacause it is equal to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n}\sqrt{ln(n)}-x_{n}\sqrt{ln(n+1)}+\frac{\sqrt{ln(n)} }{nx_{n}}}{\sqrt{ln(n)}-\sqrt{ln(n+1)}}$ but the limit of $\frac{\sqrt{ln(n)} }{nx_{n}}$ is 0. So the final value of the limit will be $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}$ which is infinity.

Comment: What I did wrong?

Comment: In the 2nd line of what you wrote, you applied the Stolz–Cesàro theorem, right? If so, that theorem only applies when the sequence in the denominator (monotonically) approaches $+ \infty$ or $-\infty$. However, the sequence in the denominator approaches $0$.

Comment: There exists aswell 0/0 stolz cesaro case

Comment: @StefanSolomon But the limit of $\frac{\sqrt{\ln(n)}}{nx_n}$ over $\sqrt{\ln(n)}-\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}$ may not be zero; actually from the correct answer we can see it's not.